# Common table for 2 tables (One to many)

Tags: mysql

Last month I've started normalising my tables, and everything goes well till now, but I have small difficulty, and I need your knowledge and opinions.

So, I have 3 tables:

```
`Table: TheMovies`
---------------------
| id      | MovieName 
---------------------
| 1       | Zootopia 
| 2       | Moana 
| 3       | Toy Story

`Table: TheSeries`
---------------------
| id      | SeriesName 
---------------------
| 1       | Vampire Diaries 
| 2       | Arrow 
| 3       | Don't have any idea

`Table: TheServers`
---------------------
| movie_id | Server  
---------------------
| 1        | youtube 
| 2        | dailymotion 
| 3        | youtube
```

The Table `TheServers` has a many-to-one relationship with `TheMovies`, and `TheSeries` table is a new table.
What I am trying to do is use `TheServers` table for both `TheMovies` and `TheSeries` table.

That's all my creativity, and what I really need is your help in planning how to design those 3 tables.

Maybe change `TheServers` to `TheMoviesServers` and create another table `TheSeriesServers` so each `TheMovies` and `TheSeries` have their own servers table.

Please guide me in this issue.

Comment: What I actually need is relationship based on 2 columns instead of 1, is that possible in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one-to-many

You need a `media_type` table and still should create the `server` table:

```
-------------------------
| media_type_id | media_type
-------------------------
| 1             | Movies
| 2             | Series

---------------------
| server_id | Server  
---------------------
| 1         | youtube 
| 2         | dailymotion
```

And Include that field on your `TheServers` table

```
`Table: TheServers`
-------------------------------------
| video_id | media_type_id  | server_id 
-------------------------------------
| 1        |       1        | 1
| 2        |       1        | 2
| 3        |       1        | 1
| 1        |       2        | 2
| 2        |       2        | 2
| 3        |       2        | 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need update the table `Servers`.

```
---------------------
| server_id | Server  
---------------------
| 1         | youtube 
| 2         | dailymotion
```

and include that field as `Foreign Key` on your other tables.

```
`Table: TheMovies`
------------------------------------------
| id      | MovieName   | server_id
------------------------------------------
| 1       | Zootopia    |    1
| 2       | Moana       |    2
| 3       | Toy Story   |    1

`Table: TheSeries`
------------------------------------------
| id      | SeriesName          | server_id
------------------------------------------
| 1       | Vampire Diaries     |
| 2       | Arrow               |
| 3       | Don't have any idea |
```

Comment: This will make it one-to-one, and I need one-to-many relationship.